# Accessing an attribute of a map Entry (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class:

```
class Entry1(var type:String, var kind:String, var index:Int)
```

And a map:

```
var map1 = mutableMapOf<String, Entry>()
```

How would I access the attributes of Entry1 of a given map entry?

Example: Say I have:

```
map1["ex1"] = Entry("ex2","ex3",4)
```

Now I want to get the `index`from the Entry I've added.

How can that be done?

Comment: What is your actual coding question? Remember stackoverflow is not for network management concepts but for programming. Usually you give your code which has a problem and ask for help on it.

Comment: different IPs being mapped to same MAC (MitM one iface) and statistics (unusual high rate of ARPs per source as one typically has to keep on poisoning the caches), flip-floping cache entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
val entry = map1["ex1"]
if (entry != null) {
    val index = entry.index;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
val entry = map1["ex1"]
val index = entry?.let{
  entry.index
} ?: -1 //optional
```